# Rename a batch of values with xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, backwards-compatibility

We have a program that uses xml to save configurations of our program. Someone decided to rename a couple of values in our database and these renames should now also be backwards compatible in the configurations of our customers.

An example of a configuration

```
<configuration>
    <fruitToEat>yellow_curved_thing</fruitToEat> <!-- should now become banana -->
</configuration>
```

A simple match would be (not tested, just an example):

```
<xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match"/configuration/fruitToEat/text()">
    <xsl:text>banana</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:template>
```

But this is just one example and I want to do this 150 times.

> *Is it possible to make an xsl that reads a simple text file or ini file that tells me how the 150 matches should look alike?*

```
<xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- recreate this template 150 times from an ini file or something -->
  <xsl:template match"/configuration/fruitToEat/text()[.='yellow_curved_thing']">
    <xsl:text>banana</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:template>
```

An example of my mapping file could be simply:

```
yellow_curved_thing = banana
round_thing = tomato
round_dotted = strawberry
```

And I would simply want a small xslt that tells me:

```
<xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- recreate this template 150 times from an ini file or something -->
  <xsl:template match"/configuration/fruitToEat/text()[.=$fileRow0]">
    <xsl:text>$fileRow1</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a big deal if you consider your "ini file" as xml file. Use something like `select="document('ini_file.xml').."`  to access this filter. But your request is far to vague to know if  either this makes sense, or if it would be better to implement this rules explicit in xlst.

Comment: So I would have to make a new xml and could simply just make the xslt explicit for all rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So even if I think there is more complexity behind the curtain, may be this will help a little bit.
There are some possibilities to do this with xlst. Which would be best in long term depends on complexity in real life and how often you need to do this with different "mapping" information.

For your easy example you can put the "mapping" information into a xml file. This could be done by some script form ini file.

```
<mappings>
    <mapping name="fruitToEat" >
        <map  from="yellow_curved_thing" to="banana"  />
        <map  from="round_thing" to="tomato"  />
        <map  from="round_dotted" to="strawberry"  />
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

Than you can have a template which make use of this mapping information:

```
<xsl:variable name="fruitMapping"
             select="document('fruitmapping.xml')//mapping[@name='fruitToEat']" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/configuration/fruitToEat/text()"  >
        <!-- find the entry in "ini file" -->
        <xsl:variable name ="map" select="$fruitMapping/map[@from = current()]" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$map" >
                <xsl:value-of select="$map/@to"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

But if this is a onetime job I would implement this "mapping"  direct a template. Like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/configuration/fruitToEat/text()" >
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=".='yellow_curved_thing'" >banana</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test=".='round_thing'" >tomato</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test=".='round_dotted'" >strawberry</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you wanted to create your XSLT dynamic XSLT on the basis of your configuration file which is also an XML document. Have a look this exmple considering this:

**configuration.xml**

```
    <p>
  <configuration>
    <fruitToEat>yellow_curved_thing</fruitToEat>
    <mapped>banana</mapped>
  </configuration>
  <configuration>
    <fruitToEat>round_thing</fruitToEat>
    <mapped>tomato</mapped>
  </configuration>
</p>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="xsl:stylesheet">
      <xsl:attribute name="version">
        <xsl:text>1.0</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:element name="xsl:template">
        <xsl:attribute name="match">
          <xsl:text>node()|@*</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="xsl:copy">
          <xsl:element name="xsl:apply-templates">
            <xsl:attribute name="select">
              <xsl:text>node()|@*</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:for-each select="//configuration">
        <xsl:element name="xsl:template">
          <xsl:attribute name="match">
            <xsl:text>configuration/fruitToEat/text()[.=</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="fruitToEat"/>
            <xsl:text>']</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:element name="xsl:text">
              <xsl:value-of select="mapped"/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="configuration/fruitToEat/text()[.='yellow_curved_thing']">
      <xsl:text>banana</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="configuration/fruitToEat/text()[.='round_thing']">
      <xsl:text>tomato</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you considering to apply the xsl to the configuration to get a new xsl? That is not what I was looking for. In the output I'm missing "banana", "tomato", "strawberry" that is mapped from "yellow_curved", "round_red" and "round_dotted".

Comment: From where you wants to pick this information 'banana', 'tomato' etc. Is this information also in configuration file? You may enhance my shared XML file to keep these information so that you can manipulate it easily.

Comment: Yes I want to have an ini file or something that contains a mapping of one name to another. I thought that it would be easy to read the file and generate the xslt, but it seems quite hard to build instead of just generating this via C# or something.

Comment: Pls. check I just change XML configuration file to get your desired output.